# doubts on pyinstaller and making a .exe file as a service on windows

Tags: python, tkinter, service, exe

i have created a GUI for my python program and made it as an .exe using pyinstaller.

my app.py imports config.py module which contains few global variables, a username, and password, as of now I have hard-coded them.

is it possible to actually assign values to variables in config.py using the GUI and save them ( in config.py ) for next time the app is executed? but i can't find my config.py once i make an .exe file

also when I execute pyinstaller app.py, I don't see my modules in the `/dist`. but the [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html) say this:-

> Another advantage of a one-folder bundle is that when you change your
> code, as long as it imports exactly the same set of dependencies, you
> could send out only the updated myscript executable.

how can I change the code when I cannot find my modules?

I would like to make this .exe file as a service. (is it not professional to launch GUI's that require input as a service?)

I would like to achieve the following:-

1. GUI to prompt user for usernames, passwords, and other variables during the first launch of the .exe
   file and then save these in config.py (which i cannot find once i make the .exe file).
2. then use this info in config.py for further executions, when it runs as a service.
3. when the app (i.e is the .exe file) is executed again (which means that user wants to change some data in the config.py), stop the current running service and then run the service with updated config.py data.

could you please help me with the above?

thanks for your time in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I would personnaly

- create 2 exe: one for the service, one for the gui
- have the configuration in a text file, not in a py (that will not be modifiable if embedded in the exe). I suggest having a look at configparser.ConfigParser() for instance.
- have the service re-read the configuration periodically

Regarding pyinstaller question please provide your build command

Comment: the command I used was ```pyinstaller.exe --onefile -icon=file.ico app.py```

Comment: I guess you meant --icon. Do you see app.exe in the dist folder ? This is what is produced by --onefile option. use --onedir instead if you want to see was the quoted comment says

Comment: yeah my bad, i meant --icon=file.ico, i used the --onedir option. i'm still not able to find the modules i created in the directory ```\dist\app\ ``` . i can only see some python core libraries and the .exe file.

Comment: Are the modules imported by app.py ?

Comment: I am only using --one-file so I took one of my app and made it onedir. Same thing as you: an exe and a bunch of libs. I read the full chapter and I believe the good interpretation is that only the dependencies outside the project are in the folder. The .py files belonging to the project are part of the exe.